# Need help using Touchegg with Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: gnome, touchpad, multi-touch, gestures, touchegg

I have installed Touchegg using

```
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

I created the configuration file using

```
mkdir ~/.config/touchegg
gedit ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```

and created a gesture to go back on webpages:

```
<gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="ALL">
        <action type="MOUSE_CLICK">BUTTON=8</action>
    </gesture>
```

Nothing is happening when I perform a 3 finger gesture in Chrome.  I understand that Touchegg cannot be used with Unity, but I haven't seen anything regarding compatibility problems with Gnome 3.14.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Is it only for 3 finger and less gestures? if so, it may be because synaptics is using them, try

```
synclient TapButton3=0 && synclient ClickFinger3=0
```

that will disable 3 finger actions from synaptics and use touchegg's actions. Similarly by disabling 2finger scroll and tap, you can get touchegg's 2 finger pinch to work (along with touchegg's inferior 2 finger scroll).

Answer (score 1):

This works on Ubuntu 15.10;

Create a `.xprofile` file in `~` with:

```
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=0
touchegg &
```

Reboot and Touchegg works.